# set tflite interpreter gpu delegate on android，it's output is different without gpu delegate

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

set tflite interpreter gpu delegate on android，it's output is different without gpu delegate, and it seems that whatever data i fed, the model output is the same, is it something wrong with my code ？and i have checked my code, it's output is correct without set the gpu delegate.

here is the code i set the tflite interpreter options:

```
tfliteModel = loadModelFile(activity);
    switch (device) {
        case NNAPI:
            tfliteOptions.setUseNNAPI(true);
            break;
        case GPU:
            gpuDelegate = new GpuDelegate();
            tfliteOptions.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
            break;
        case CPU:
            break;
    }
    tfliteOptions.setNumThreads(numThreads);
    tflite = new Interpreter(tfliteModel, tfliteOptions);
```

and here is the code i used to inference(where the input is a four dim array, and output is a two dim array, corresponding to the model input and output dimentions):

```
tflite.run(audioData, output);
```

and i found some error log about libEGL,is it related to the problem?
My device is RK3288.

> I/tflite: Created TensorFlow Lite delegate for GPU.
>   2017-01-02 15:34:11.327 2603-2603/com.example.dm.testing I/tflite: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
>   2017-01-02 15:34:11.380 2603-2603/com.example.dm.testing I/mali_so: [File] : hardware/arm/maliT760/driver/product/base/src/mali_base_kbase.c; [Line] : 876; [Func] : base_context_deal_with_version_affairs_rk_ext;
>       arm_release_ver of this mali_so is 'r18p0-01rel0', rk_so_ver is '3@0'.
>   2017-01-02 15:34:11.380 2603-2603/com.example.dm.testing D/mali_so: [File] : hardware/arm/maliT760/driver/product/base/src/mali_base_kbase.c; [Line] : 881; [Func] : base_context_deal_with_version_affairs_rk_ext;
>       current process is NOT sf, to bail out.
>   2017-01-02 15:34:11.386 2603-2603/com.example.dm.testing E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
>   2017-01-02 15:34:11.389 2603-2603/com.example.dm.testing E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
>   2017-01-02 15:34:12.487 2603-2628/com.example.dm.testing I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   2017-01-02 15:34:12.487 2603-2628/com.example.dm.testing D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>   2017-01-02 15:34:12.502 2603-2628/com.example.dm.testing D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
>   2017-01-02 15:34:12.527 2603-2628/com.example.dm.testing D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000